# Long trip for small reward?

Tags: idioms

There's a German idiom (I think) for a long trip for a small reward. For example, driving from New York to Boston to buy a roast beef sandwich. Has a connotation of taking a trip for the trip's sake. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Clearly you've never been to Nick's Roast Beef. Oh, and that's called a road trip. Can you give a different example?

Comment: Everyone is interpreting this as negative, but it sounds to me like the original idiom might have positive connotations?

Comment: _Taking the scenic route?_

Comment: There are two different concepts here: 'taking a long trip for a disproportionately small reward' and 'taking a long trip where the trip itself, not the arriving etc, is considered ample reward'. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 6):

Agreeing with the suggestion of @ChrisSunami that the "connotation of taking a trip for the trip's sake" is not necessarily a negative one, I would offer a quote attributed to T.S. Eliot:

“[The journey, not the arrival matters](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/657162-the-journey-not-the-arrival-matters),”

which seems to capture this positive notion as does the following idiom:

> [Getting there is half the fun.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/getting+there+is+half+the+fun)

Comment: +1 Another phrasing, *It's the journey, not the destination.*

Answer (score 5):

*[Tripping over dollars to pick up pennies](http://witandbanter.blogspot.com/2008/05/tripping-over-dollars-to-pick-up-dimes.html)* communicates the idea of wasting resources for small rewards.

Of course in America they said "*[I'd walk a mile for a Camel](https://www.google.com/search?q=i%27d%20walk%20a%20mile%20for%20a%20camel&espv=2&biw=1247&bih=568&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=sH3JVJqiJIaFyQSU6IG4Dg&ved=0CB0QsAQ)*. That's actually a long trip to kill yourself ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*[Much ado about nothing](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/much_ado/full.html)*?

-W. Shakespeare

Answer (score 0):

One older saying that seems to condemn the practice of investing much (or even a modest amount of) expense in return for a slight benefit is "the game is not worth the candle." Gregory Titelman, *The Random House Dictionary of American Popular Proverbs and Sayings* (2000) explains the saying this way:

> **The game is not worth the candle.** The gain is not worth the effort. The saying dates from the pre-electric era, when candles were used for lighting; thus, continuing a game at night was not worth even the cost of the candles. The proverb is of French origin. Michel de Montaigne (1533–92) is quoted as saying, *Le jeu ne vaut pas la chandelle*. It was included in John Ray's collection of proverbs. Although it is usually used in the negative, the affirmative version, *The game is worth the candle*, is also sometimes heard.

Actually, John Ray's [*A Collection of English Proverbs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=VuhDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA20&dq=%22It%27s+a+poor+sport+that+is+not+worth+the+candle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_YzJVLKWGIbdoASumIKACw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22It%27s%20a%20poor%20sport%20that%20is%20not%20worth%20the%20candle%22&f=false) (1678, 1737, etc.) has this wording:

> It's a poor *sport* that is not worth the candle.

which seems to say that a game must be exceptionally bad not to justify the price of lighting the room so that you can play it. Still, in either form, the saying invites hearers to conduct an informal comparison of cost to benefit before undertaking a project.

---

In my family, we had the expression "Drink a martini to get to the olive"—a reference to an incident in which I was the surreptitious, two-year-old, olive-loving protagonist. For most people, however, that expression wouldn't make sense, because getting to the olive is supposed to be the best part.

Answer (score 0):

for a saying that has a connotation of taking a trip for the trip's sake i found no better than American Jewish writer Muriel Rukeyser's: "the journey is my home"!

http://cdn2-b.examiner.com/sites/default/files/styles/image_content_width_large/hash/df/49/df49a79c1a812bb2170bcfd8789e6c1b.jpg?itok=xgNWJa_l

Answer (score -1):

It seemes to me a case of ***using a sledgehammer to crack a nut***.

Comment: Close, but no cigar: that expression doesn't mean 'a long trip for a small reward'. 'Using a sledgehammer to crack a nut' means 'to use a disproportionately violent or powerful method to achieve only a modest or marginal outcome'.